# Determining root cause of strange colors in VLC

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, vlc-media-player, nvidia-geforce, video-codecs

Recently I am getting strange colors when playing a video file in VLC. This does not occur all the time, but at random intervals. When I restart VLC the same video file plays fine.

Screen of VLC:
[image]

After some googling I found this can be "fixed" by adjusting the 'hardwaredecode' setting in VLC itself.

As a related issue when I have multiple tabs open in my browser (Chrome) and I close a tab, it has issues displaying the previous tab. To clarify, I still see part of the contents of the closed tab in the current tab. But again, this just happens sometimes and when I move the mouse around the 'old' content disappears.
Will add a screenshot the next time this occurs.

How do i get the root cause of this issue? I would like to fix this issue completely, rather than bypass the issue in VLC by adjusting some settings.

Further usefull data:
- This issue only started recently, worked fine before.
- I own a Intel Core i7-4790K, 16GB RAM, NVidia GeForce GTX 970
- I performed a memory test, which did not reveal any issues
- I ran 3DMark benchmark to see if my GFX card would fail but results were excellent
- I have not installed or changed any codecs that could cause the issue to appear (also I don't believe chrome uses codecs to display content, so this should not be relevant)
- Temperatures of the CPU is on avarage 42 degrees celcius. GPU is 37. (could be lower but I have fans on silent mode)

Hope someone can assist. Thank you.

Comment: I have seen this color fail of this type before it can be caused by at least 2 things. When the compressed and animated (frames depend on previous frames) encodes, If there are tiny errors in the orignal prior to encode, in the encoding process, or in the file itself as transfered about.   When the specific codec  that is chosen (by the sytem or player) to decode the video does not decode it properly, this occurs more often when complicated codec methods are applied to save space (within the same quality) .  (almost) All videos are decoded with some codec, be that built-in or seperate codecs..

Comment: If it is a codec issue than why does the same file run fine when I close VLC and play that same file again? Shouldn't the same file always have this color issue if the codec is having issues?

Comment: yes, if it is a codec issue or a file problem it would show the same way each time, Because it is built on the previous frames though you would play it at least from a few keyframes back to see if it does it again.  Hopping only back to that section again may not reveal the error.

Comment: If this issue occurs it occurs throughout the entire video file, not just part of it. But since the issue disappears if I restart VLC, a codec issue does not seem to be the issue. Nor would that explain the strange browser issue.

Comment: I have recently updated the LAV splitter (https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/releases) and the issue with VLC seems to have been solved. Does not explain the chrome issue but that might not be related after all. I'll keep an eye on it and if it is indeed fixed, I'll post this solution as the anwer.

Comment: Issue just occured again, so it wasn't the LAV filter either.

Comment: Could be time to do a full memtest86 boot from a usb stick , test for overnight, and absolve the memory for any issues, then do a quick smart test on the drives to check thier status. Then to absolve the GPU stuff , change up the "renderer" in the video player, switch it to an overlay , software, or direct draw sort of render vrses a 3D render.  this is easy and a wider array of options for render in Media Player Classic, although WMP and VLC have switches for overlay.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  I do not know the root cause of the issue, but I can tell you how I fixed it and maybe someone can work it out from there.

1) Tools -> Preferences -> Video

2) Un-check "Use hardware YUV->RGB conversions
(Under display section in simple view)

This has fixed it for me, been watching for a few days with no repeat errors.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked for me, although it appears to be happening a whole lot less often now. I'm still trying stuff, so if I ever find out I'll post back

Comment: this worked for me . using latest nvidia stable drivers. gtx 660. I didnt even think I could search for this issue and the gfji result highlights its ego lines  so I did not actually see the title of this post but something entirely. I just ""felt lucky" and clicked it.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics card manufacturers often optimize decoded video. This may be a bug if you solve it by using software decoding.

The recommended solution is update your driver and system.

Comment: The latest drivers are installed. If it is a hardware issue how would I determine that?

Comment: First you can try using official media player by windows. Your GPU seems to be new, so it doesn't seem to be problematic. Mentioned by @psycogeek, it may be a video issue. Try big buck bunny is a good way to check it.

Comment: I downloaded all versions if this big buck bunny and all seem to work fine. What should happen is something is wrong?

Comment: If your driver is f**ked up, it should got color issue when playing H.264 version(others may varies by implementation) with software decoding off. You should temporarily use software decoding for the tricky encoded movie.